# Highlighting code with AngularJS and Highlight.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, highlight.js

I'm trying to highlight code inside a `<pre><code>` block.

The twist is that the code is being injected with Angular's `ng-bind-html`:

```
<div ng-controller="postsController">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <div ng-bind-html="post"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `post` variable contains HTML and somewhere inside there's a `<pre><code>` block. I can make everything work outside Angular and even tried [angular-highlightjs](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs), but didn't get any luck. There are similar questions here, but they aren't quite like my case.

Can anyone help please? Thank you!

AP

Comment: did you include ngSanitize?

Comment: Hi Oliver, yes, the HTML injection is working just fine. It's just that the code block isn't being highlighted.

Comment: Did you try using the hljs directive which comes with Highlight JS? My guess is `<div hljs source="post"></div>` should work... Otherwise please provide a jsfiddle so we can take a deeper look at the problem...